# BAT run python and kill it after period of time

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

Using the script below within a BAT file

```
pushd C:\Users\Me
python -m bot_py synology
```

I execute a python script which **never** has an exit point (runs forever).

How can I tell within my BAT file that after a period of time, for example 5 hours, the python script should be killed/exited?

Comment: Task Scheduler is meant for this sort of thing... but if you must use a batch file, you can get the process ID via something like `tasklist | findstr`... then kill that process `taskkill /F /PID 18424`. This has some hints on getting the PID from a tasklist search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555929/get-only-pid-from-tasklist-using-cmd-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a batch file to demonstrate some components for your solution:
**Note:** Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561117/11639518) for the PID extraction, pointed out by @JacobIRR.

```
TITLE Synology-Script

@echo off
for /F "tokens=2" %%K in ('
    tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Synology-Script" /FI "Status eq Running" /FO LIST ^| findstr /B "PID:"    
') do (
    set pid=%%K
   echo %%K
)
echo "I'm scheduled to stop execution in 10 seconds"

timeout /t 10 /nobreak>nul
taskkill /PID %pid% /F
```

I used the TITLE paremeter to give me something to search for, and searched for that in the tasklist filter command on offer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012345/windows-cmd-tasklist-fi-windowtitle-eq-doesnt-work). I recommend [*not* including spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012345/windows-cmd-tasklist-fi-windowtitle-eq-doesnt-work) in your title. I used this pid as an argument to taskkill, which terminates this process.

```
timeout /t 10 /nobreak>nul
```

This lets us sleep for 5 seconds, and stuffs the 'press ctrl+c' to nul, to keep it out of sight. You could set the 5 to whatever your desired sleep interval is.